# Java XPath evaluation return type

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Is there a way to identify what the return type of an XPath evaluation would be? I want XPath to match as generically as possible. It should match a nodelist, and if can't, a node, and if can't, a value. Is there an easy way to implement this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many difficulties with the design of the JAXP XPath API and this is one of them. Consider using Saxon as your XPath processor, which will (a) enable you to use XPath 2.0, and (b) give you the benefits of the much richer s9api API. [Shameless plug]

Answer (score 1):

You should know the return type of the evaluation because you provided it to `evaluate`. For example:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/expression");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you're dealing with the result of an evaluation that you did not perform yourself (i.e. you've just been handed some `Object`), then resort to normal `instanceof` checks.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to invoke it without knowing the return type and getting the broadest.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using the standard JAXP implementation, but you could using [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/). It has a `selectNodes()` function which returns a `List` of objects. The list will contain `Attribute`, `Content` or Text (and maybe others I've yet to encounter). You will need to pass it a JDom document.

```
org.jdom.Document doc = builder.build(file);
org.jdom.xpath.XPath xp = XPath.newInstance("expression here");
List nodes = xpath.selectNodes(document);
for (Object node : nodes) {
   if (node instanceof Attribute) {
     value = ((Attribute) node).getValue();
   } else if (node instanceof Content) {
     value = ((Content) node).getValue();
   } else if (node instanceof Text) {
     value = (Text) node.getText();
   }
}
```