# How to distinguish between attribute and element nodes returned from a Saxon XPathSelector

Tags: java, xpath, saxon, s9api

Given the XML:

```
<root name="value">
  <level1>
    <level2>Text</level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

I want the XPath `/root/@name` to return `value`, and the XPath `/root/level1` to return the XML serialisation of the `<level1>` node:

```
  <level1>
    <level2>Text</level2>
  </level1>
```

I'm using the a9api interface from Saxon 9.6 in Java.

I've found that I can call [`XdmValue.toString()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmValue.html#toString()) to get the XML serialisation of the result of the evaluation of the XPath, which gets me the desired result for selecting an element, but returns `name="value"` when selecting an attribute. And I can call [`XdmItem.getStringValue()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmItem.html#getStringValue()) to get the [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#acc-summ-string-value), which gets me the right value for the attribute, but returns the textual content of the element.

Michael Kay has previously [said "Saxon's s9api interface ... returns XdmValue objects whose type you can interrogate"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7018824/1216210). I can see that I could perform an `instanceof` check to determine whether it is an `XdmAtomicValue`, `XdmExternalObject`, `XdmFunctionItem`, or `XdmNode`, but elements and attributes are both instances of `XdmNode`. How do I distinguish between the two?

(I can't modify the XPaths, as they're provided by the user.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer just as I finished writing the question, so I'll share it for others.

After casting the `XdmItem` to an `XdmNode`, you can call [`XdmNode.getNodeKind()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmNode.html#getNodeKind()), which returns a value from the [`XdmNodeKind`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmNodeKind.html) enumeration specifying which type of node it is:

```
        XdmValue matchList = xPathSelector.evaluate();
        XdmItem firstItem = matchList.itemAt(0);
        if (firstItem instanceof XdmNode) {
           XdmNode xdmNode = (XdmNode) firstItem;
           XdmNodeKind nodeKind = xdmNode.getNodeKind();
           if (nodeKind == XdmNodeKind.ELEMENT) {
              return xdmNode.toString();
           }
        }
        return firstItem.getStringValue();
```